# Upgrading Magento EE1.10.to 1.12 shows up issue add to cart button disappear after customer login

Tags: magento

While upgrading magento EE1.10 to 1.12 everything seems to work fine but during testing , when a customer log in from front-end the add to cart button and the price Div disappear.

Then I change the design package and template to the "enterprise" I found the similar issues, I guess that This issue is not related to the design but somewhere else,

I am not able to find out what is the exact problem,

Does any body have any idea what maybe the issue?

After enabling log i found this

```
2013-03-02T10:53:27+00:00 ERR (3): 
SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string '\xad...' is not a valid utf-8 string in /www/sites/xxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php:410
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('getRates', Array)
#1 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php(410): SoapClient->getRates(Array)
#2 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php(443): Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex->_doRatesRequest('general')
#3 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php(186): Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex->_getQuotes()
#4 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php(207): Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex->collectRates(Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#5 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php(129): Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping->collectCarrierRates('fedex', Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#6 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php(888): Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping->collectRates(Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#7 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php(819): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->requestShippingRates()
#8 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Shipping.php(155): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectShippingRates()
#9 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php(957): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping->collect(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))
#10 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1263): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectTotals()
#11 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/local/Idev/OneStepCheckout/Model/Sales/Quote.php(27): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->collectTotals()
#12 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php(210): Idev_OneStepCheckout_Model_Sales_Quote->collectTotals()
#13 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Observer.php(44): Mage_Checkout_Model_Session->loadCustomerQuote()
#14 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Checkout_Model_Observer->loadCustomerQuote(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#15 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Checkout_Model_Observer), 'loadCustomerQuo...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#16 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('customer_login', Array)
#17 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php(195): Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', Array)
#18 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php(183): Mage_Customer_Model_Session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
#19 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(149): Mage_Customer_Model_Session->login('IL876510@farrla...', 'abcd.1234')
#20 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Customer_AccountController->loginPostAction()
#21 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('loginPost')
#22 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /www/sites/xxxxx/files/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}
```